How can I pass in a JSON file to AWS Sagemaker Batch Transform
It's very unclear on the documentation how to run an AWS Sagemaker Batch transform job with a JSON input file. It seems to be better documented for CSV files.
Assuming I want to run a transform job with an input.json file, what is the required structure for this?
Here is my request to Sagemaker
...
batch_job_name = "batch-test-01"
model_name = "fr-model-1"
payload_size = 1
max_concurrent_tranform_jobs = 100
environment_variables = {}
input_s3_path = "s3://{bucket_name}/input.json"
output_s3_path = "s3://{bucket_name}/batch-output/"
instance_type = "ml.m5.xlarge"
instance_count = 1

request = {
    "TransformJobName": batch_job_name,
    "ModelName": model_name,
    "MaxPayloadInMB": payload_size,
    "BatchStrategy": "SingleRecord",
    "MaxConcurrentTransforms": max_concurrent_tranform_jobs,
    "Environment": environment_variables,
    "TransformInput": {
        "DataSource": {
            "S3DataSource": {
                "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                "S3Uri": input_s3_path
            }
        },
        "ContentType": "application/json",
        "SplitType": "Line",
        "CompressionType": "None"
    },
    "TransformOutput": {
        'S3OutputPath': output_s3_path,
    },
    "TransformResources": {
        "InstanceType": instance_type,
        "InstanceCount": instance_count
    }
}

try:
    response = sagemaker_client.create_transform_job(**request)
    print("Batch Transform job created:", response['TransformJobArn'])
except Exception as e:
    print("Error creating Batch Transform job:", str(e))
...

I've tried the following input.json file but I am receiving a 500 Internal Server Error when giving this a run. It isn't reaching the application code so I am quite certain it is either an issue with the request I am making above or the contents of the input.json file below:
...
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" } // each on its own line
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }
...


Are there any logs in the CloudWatch regarding this job ?
